# Encoding or other error with static files in tornado

Tags: python, static, tornado

I need help with static files(html, scryptes, pictures, css) in tornado. Standart file handler is not useful, becuse request url must not contain static prefix.
Server is used in mobile application project.

The code:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/(.*)", static),
])


class static(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
def get(self, url):
    print 'static', url
    try:
        data = open(r'static/'+url,'rb').read()
        print 'file found', url
    except:
        data = 'error. file not found'
        print 'file not found', url
    self.write(data)
```

Atempt to get picture failed. browser shows different characters. 
html pages are shown, but it seems css load faled.

is thre any way to do it?

python 2.7, windows 7 x64 (just for test).

problem solved:

```
    (r"/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": r"C:\Python27\***\static"}),
```

Comment: does `static` in your `Application` definition refer to `tornado.web.StaticFileHandler`? Could you prefix your static handler url with something like `r'/static/(.*)'` ?http://stackoverflow.com/a/9637895/594589

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle a HTTP GET request to a file in Tornado?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531092/how-to-handle-a-http-get-request-to-a-file-in-tornado)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tornado's ability to server static file:

```
application = tornado.web.Application(
    [(r"/(.*)", static)],
    static_path="your path here"
)
```

but it implies calling the url: 
`www.domain.com/static/anyfile.txt`

EDIT:
If you want to have a different base url, you could add the param:
`static_url_prefix="/toto/"` when creating application

then: `www.domain.com/toto/anyfile.txt` would serve your file